# Visual Studio 2010 cannot build projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a weird problem.

I just installed visual studio 2010 RTM on windows 7 Ultimate. I have two problems!

1) File->New Project returns empty templates. Cannot create a project. But if I open a solution I can add project in the solution.

2) I cannot build the project! No matter what I tried build project returns only

```
------ Build started: Project: WindowsFormsApplication1, Configuration: Release Any CPU ----- 
========= Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

It only creates *vhost.exe files but not the exe. I tried to set detailed output in build but the same message appears. Even Cleaning the project does the same thing

I installed and reinstalled VS2010 several times. I installed it as Administrator and I also put "Everyone" to be allowed in the VS2010 install folder. My other co-workers installed it correctly from the same DVD.

can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Do you have all the other pre-requisites installed? Also, try running  VS 2010 as administrator, I mean not just installation but the launching as well.

Comment: What other pre-requisites? VS installs them automatically. And yes I have installed it, and run it as administrator

Answer (score -1):

so the only solution was to format my system and re-install windows 7 :(